# 1 Hour Window Sum Calculation in SQL for 5 minute intervals

Tags: sql, excel, sum, window, powerquery

I have a transaction schedule that has a date, time (nearest 5 minutes) and a price ($). The schedule covers almost a year of data, about 100k rows.

The aim  is to get a 1 hour window sum of the price for every 5 minute interval for the year i.e. at 105pm I want to know the sum of prices between 105pm and 205pm that day, then a sum for 110-210pm, 115-215pm etc for the entire year - for a year there would be 12x24x365 rows in the report. This should also be able to calculate across midnight (e.g. sum of 11:55pm to 12:55am the next day)
There can be multiple transactions happening at the same time as well.

What is the best way to do this sum in SQL if my table looks like this:

```
| TransactDate| TransactTime| PurchasePrice|
|:---- |:------:| -----:|
| 1/2/2021| 1:05:00PM| $30|
| 1/2/2021| 1:10:00PM| $40|
| 1/2/2021| 1:15:00PM| $10|
```

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: Excel and PowerQuery